# How to start threads in Flask without the page freezing?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm making a Flask app where I paste several torrent info hashes in a textarea and my app would start downloading those torrents. This is my code:

```
        # app.py
    content = request.form['downloads']
    info_hashes = content.strip().strip('\n').split('\n')
    threads = []
    try:
        for h in info_hashes:
            threads.append(threading.Thread(target=downloader(h)))

        for t in threads:
            t.start()

        flash('Download started.')

    except Exception as e:
        flash(str(e))





# downloader.py
from torrentp import TorrentDownloader

def downloader(info_hash):
        SAVE_PATH = '/media/zemen/HDD/jellyfin'
        torrent_file = TorrentDownloader(f"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:{info_hash}", SAVE_PATH)
        torrent_file.start_download()
```

So my problem is that while the downloads are happening my website just keeps loading. How do I make the downloads run in the background? Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not starting the threads properly.

```
threading.Thread(target=downloader(h))
```

Here you are assigning whatever is the result (probably `None` in this case) of `downloader(h)` as the target for the thread, not the downloader function itself. In other words, you are not starting the download in a thread at all, but trying to do it beforehand instead.

`threading.Thread` expects a callable + args, so you need to pass a reference to the function instead, like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=downloader, args=[h])
```

See examples in https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread for more information.

Comment: My friend now for some reason only one thread is starting, the others get discarded.

Comment: That's a bit strange. Try to add more prints if you don't alreadiy have to confirm for example that `info_hashes` and `threads` really contain multiple items.

Comment: So I opted for subprocessess as I think that is more suitable for this task.